# How to change the transparency of the confidence interval in a relplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I found an answer for regplots, but I can't get the same code to work for relplots. I want to change the transparency of the confidence intervals while keeping the lines of my graph darker, but the alpha input for relplots makes the entire graph more translucent.

My code:

```
cookie = sns.relplot(
    data=data, x="Day", y="Touches", 
    hue='Sex', ci=68, kind="line", col = 'Event'
    )
```

The line that works for regplots is

```
plt.setp(cookie.collections[1], alpha=0.4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While, `regplot` returns one `ax` (subplot), `relplot` returns a complete grid of subplots (a `FacetGrid`). Often, the return value is grabbed into a variable named `g` (calling it `cookie` can make things very confusing when comparing with code from the documents).

You can loop through the individual axes of the `FacetGrid` and make the change for each of them:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fmri = sns.load_dataset('fmri')
g = sns.relplot(data=fmri, x="timepoint", y="signal", col="region",
                hue="event", style="event", kind="line")
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.collections[-1].set_alpha(0.4)

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.relplot with changed transparency]

PS: As mentioned in the comments, if you want to change the alpha of all confidence intervals (instead of just one of them, as in the code of the question), you can use `sns.relplot(..., err_kws={"alpha": .4})`.

Comment: This isn't necessary; use `err_kws={"alpha": .4}`.